# Excel sorted heading won't sort data in whole spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, spreadsheet

So I would like to be able sort all my data using the little drop down arrow created by the filter function, all the way from F to JE. 
At the moment it will only sort from F to AK.

Any idea how I can fix this? It needs to sort regardless of whether there are blanks or not

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you highlight all the data you want to filter / sort before you hit filter.

Answer (score 0):

All your Column should have headers even if no data under it, if the whole column is blank the sort will stop just before it